Superset. Executing Stored Procedures by changing the source code
Apache Superset runs only SELECT statements. When I try EXEC someSP against SQL SERVER then it throws me "Only SELECT statements are allowed against this database.". Because Superset is an open source software in Python Ι tried to find information how to change the code so to allow the execute of SP in Sql server (I imagine that the same problem exists with other rdbms as MySql that use Call SP and postgresql). Please I know that there are other posts in the Internet that suggest the use of OPENQUERY. I am not interested in the OPENQUERY solution that I have already test it and works. I need a solution related to python source code.
I found this post but didn't understand. They refer to things that doesn't exist or they use strange, unintelligible and unstructured speech.
Also I tried to find the source of this message to start from somewhere. I found it in the file sql_lab.py.I changed it to test if is this. And I didn't see the change!
if not db_engine_spec.is_readonly_query(parsed_query) and not database.allow_dml:
    raise SupersetErrorException(
        SupersetError(
            message=__("Only SELECT statements are allowed against the database."),
            #message=__("Only SELECT statements are allowed against this database."),
            error_type=SupersetErrorType.DML_NOT_ALLOWED_ERROR,
            level=ErrorLevel.ERROR,
        )
    )

At the end I can refactor the SPs to run on table value functions (Superset can run functions because is used SELECT) but I want to avoid it.
Is there a way to allow Superset to not limited to the SELECT? I am using version 3.
